# How to clone table in db2?

Tags: db2

I want to clone a table in DB2 . My requirement is to create the new table using base table and In the new table I need same number of columns and I don't need the data of old table.please help me how to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance ,

Raj

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In DB2, you can use this syntax:

```sql
CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE old_table
```

This will create a table of the same *type* as the original table. I doubt that indexes/keys are copied, too, though.

Here's [some documentation on that topic](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/topic/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0000927.htm)

Comment: I am getting the following error : " CREATE TABLE New_table AS SELECT * FROM Old_table
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "CREATE TABLE New_table AS" was 
found following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  
"<space>".  SQLSTATE=42601"

Comment: @Raj: I'm sorry that was Oracle-syntax. I wasn't aware that this is not supported in DB2. See the updated post

Comment: @Raj You can create a table using a select statement, but the syntax is `CREATE TABLE New_Table AS SELECT * FROM Old_table DEFINITION ONLY`

Answer (score 0):

EXCHANGE DATA BETWEEN BaseTable AND NewTable;